# Service for sending SMS notifications or Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase

I have an application developed in **Angular 7** that is in the final stage of development. This application makes use of the **Firebase** services, one of them is the **Cloud Firestore**.

I'm looking for a way to have a service that runs daily without stopping, that identifies when to send an SMS alerting the user of an appointment that he even has it closed, or send a Push Notification using **Cloud Messaging** if possible.

How can I send a reminder SMS by taking an appointment saved in **Firestore**, checking the time and day and sending an SMS or Push Notification without the user having to be logged in to the system?

I believe that I would have to have a service on a server running daily without stopping doing the readings in the database, but is there something on the Internet that does this for me without having to have a server of my own?

Comment: I think for example skebby (https://www.skebby.it/) can do something like that.

Comment: But how do I check when to send SMS from the saved logs in Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cloud functions from firebase you would be able to look in your database and detect if something needs to be done. [Click here to read more about firebase cloud functions.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases)

You will hover need something to trigger your firebase cloud function (something like a cron job). This sadly is not yet supported by cloud functions. I think [this blogpost](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) describes quite well what you want to do and how to do it (using another google service).

Sending an SMS however is not something firebase supports. You will have to use an external service for this.

Comment: Would Cloud Functions not be an extension of Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore? When does an event occur in the database a function is triggered?

Comment: I can not depend on a database event, since the user may not be logged in to the system ... He should receive the SMS reminder without being logged in to the system, verifying an appointment saved in the Firestore.

Comment: You are correct. To solve your problem you will need another small service to trigger your cloud function. I edited my answer.